# Error with sending embed link with discord webhook using JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have recently wanted to experiment with the node module for `webhook-discord` where I got an error stating `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 400 Bad Request`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webhook-discord

I installed the module using vs code's built in terminal and have copied and pasted the exact code located under "Custom Messages" and have inputted my webhook URL.

```
const webhook = require("webhook-discord");

const Hook = new webhook.Webhook("WEBHOOK URL");

const msg = new webhook.MessageBuilder()
                .setName("Username")
                .setColor("#aabbcc")
                .setText("This is my webhook!");
Hook.send(msg);
```

When I tried using other examples such as this, it works:

```
const webhook = require("webhook-discord");
const Hook = new webhook.Webhook("WEBHOOK URL");
Hook.info("WEBHOOK NAME","Info");
```

Comment: If my answer solved the problem you presented in your question, you should consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark. Or at least provide feedback to the answerers of your previous questions before asking new questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clearly an issue with the library, you should head [here](https://github.com/jb3/webhook-discord/issues) and let the authors know.

The problem is that their [`MessageBuilder`](https://github.com/jb3/webhook-discord/blob/master/lib/builder.js) always specifies a `fields` array inside of the post data. And when you don't add any fields, there is an error because the array cannot be empty. So use `.addField()` method to make it work.

```js
const Hook = new webhook.Webhook("webhook url");

const msg = new webhook.MessageBuilder()
    .setName("Username")
    .setColor("#aabbcc")
    .setText("This is my webhook!")
    .addField("Webhook Discord", "Oh, now the library works!");

Hook.send(msg);
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The authors of the library should either update their homepage or modify the library in a way that it doesn't require you to always have some `fields` specified.

Basically allow you to send payloads like this:

```json
{
    "username": "Username",
    "text": "This is my webhook!"
}
```